CSS flexbox working when applied to whole <body> but not on a specific div container


#title-row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    height:100vh;
  }

.title-img {
    z-index:1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
.title-row > p {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 135px;
    top: 130px;
  }
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
  }
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="title-row">
      <img src="images/png.png">
      <p>THE TITLE</p>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="book"><p>Book1 <br>By author1</p></div>
      <div class="book"><p>Book2<br>By author2</p></div>
      <div class="book"><p>Book3<br>By author3</p></div>
      <div class="book"></div>
      <div class="book"></div>
      <div class="book"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>



If I comment out the css for the body, the image and title on top of the img go back to top left position. But it works when applied to the body (which I don't want because I would rather the flex applied only to the title portion so I can work with grids for the main content. )
PS:I'm a beginner, just learnt flexbox and started grids so I apologize if this is an easy question, but I would really appreciate an explanation. Also, this obv isn't complete, I just want the title portion to work before I move onto the content.
tldr, Tried commenting out the body and applying flex to the title container only.

It's not quite clear what you're trying to fix.

#title-row selects an element with an ID attribute that has the value of title-row. None of your elements have IDs. Use .title-row instead to apply styles to elements with the title-row class.

Make sure that you double check your code before submitting it to Stack Overflow.

You used #title-row. Note that #title-row targets an id! Common mistake! Make sure to check your code more carefully; it happens to everyone!


.title-row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    height:100vh;
  }

.title-img {
    z-index:1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
.title-row > p {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 135px;
    top: 130px;
  }
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
  }
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="title-row">
      <img src="images/png.png">
      <p>THE TITLE</p>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="book"><p>Book1 <br>By author1</p></div>
      <div class="book"><p>Book2<br>By author2</p></div>
      <div class="book"><p>Book3<br>By author3</p></div>
      <div class="book"></div>
      <div class="book"></div>
      <div class="book"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>




You are applying display 'flex' to '#title-row'. But there is no div with id 'title-row'. You have a div with classname 'title-row'. So try changing #title-row with .title-row.

You need to describe your problem better and you need to tell us better what is your expectation to get. As from what I have seen, you have several mistakes here:

You mixed up id with class, instead of #title-row you should use .title-row
You didn't apply class to image element

Why did your code worked when you applied it to body? You wrapped like this:
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="title-row">
      <img src="images/png.png">
      <p>THE TITLE</p>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="book"><p>Book1 <br>By author1</p></div>
      <div class="book"><p>Book2<br>By author2</p></div>
      <div class="book"><p>Book3<br>By author3</p></div>
      <div class="book"></div>
      <div class="book"></div>
      <div class="book"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

So your css applied to body of course, and it positioned this div into center, and thats why your div with class .title-row and and div with class .content are positioned in center.
Also you should take notes for this in case of more problems:
When using absolute positioning its good practice to make parent relative because it will be absolute positioned based on first relative parent from the children upwards.
You can read more about positioning here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp
